# Other softwares like Wine

Tags: linux, ubuntu

Is there any other software like **Wine** for **Ubuntu** or for any other Linux distribution?

Comment: Generally you're better off asking a specific question.  For instance, if you asked "I would like to run *Sim Pope* under Ubuntu, but WINE doesn't work--is there another way?" that would be more likely to get you a useful answer.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You mean to run Windows applications ? There's [Crossover Linux](http://www.codeweavers.com/products/cxlinux/), [Crossover Games](http://www.codeweavers.com/products/cxgames/), & [Cedega](http://www.cedega.com/) - but all are paid and use the WINE codebase. Another is [Mono](http://www.mono-project.com/Main_Page) which implements the .net frameworks and runtimes on Linux.

Answer (score 1):

Although not "like Wine", Virtual Machines are a great way of running Windows applications on Linux.  There are several freely available virtual machine engines for Linux, such as [VirtualBox](http://virtualbox.org), but in order to run Windows applications you will still need a copy of Windows.

Comment: Wine is not an emulator, nor a virtual machine. It is a collection of libraries recreating Windows API.

Comment: @whitequark, Understood, but the question was not what software is implemented the same as Wine.  The end results are the same... with Wine I can run Windows apps on Linux.  With a VM I can run Windows apps on Linux.

Answer (score -1):

Wine stands (stood?) for "Wine is not an emulator".

Just about all the software available for Linux "is not an emulator" and so is just like Wine.

Comment: Doesn't really answer the question.

Comment: "Doesn't **really** answer the question"?  Doesn't answer the question at all, being an (admittedly rather poor) attempt at humour based on the rubbish names that get used for open source projects.